# When Dba_Scheduler_Jobs.Start_Date is not specified, where does Oracle store Job Enabling time

Tags: database, oracle, dbms-scheduler

I've a question on DBMS_Scheduler functionality:

When I create a scheduler job via DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB proc and I don't specify Start_Date value, then job is scheduled for execution as soon as it is enabled which is correct. I want to know where does Oracle store the Job enabling time because same enabling time can be seen in dba_scheduler_job_run_details.Req_Start_Date when job finishes.

Basically I want to see enabling time for a job which is in SCHEDULED state and Start_date value for that job is NULL.

Thanks for sharing knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

The job enabling time appears to be stored in `SYS.SCHEDULER$_JOB.LAST_ENABLED_TIME`.

But since that is an undocumented table, I can't say with great confidence that my answer is always correct.